# Google PageSpeed Insights reports that bootstrap.min.css is render blocking

Tags: seo, css, performance

I'm trying to achieve an over-90 grade on PageSpeed Insights.

My last error comes with bootstrap, Google detects the file `bootstrap.min.css` as a render blocker. The file is located in my server.

I've looked for some information online but I haven't found anything.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article that describes a process for getting a perfect 100 score on PageSpeed Insights using bootstrap:  https://www.appneta.com/blog/bootstrap-pagespeed/

They enabled mod_pagespeed Apache module with these settings:

```
ModPageSpeed on
ModPagespeedRewriteLevel CoreFilters
ModPagespeedEnableFilters prioritize_critical_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters defer_javascript
ModPagespeedEnableFilters sprite_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_png_to_jpeg,convert_jpeg_to_webp
ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace,remove_comments
```

`prioritize_critical_css` is what appears to solve the render blocking CSS.